# rails Action Mailer perform_deliveries=false is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, end-to-end

I am running rails 5.1.0

In `config/environments/test`, I have `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false`.

I am running a rails server with `-e test` to perform end to end to tests.

When I switch the server back to the dev environment, it loads a new browser tab rendering every email that wasn't sent during my tests. If I run my tests 5-6 times, this results in 50 browser tabs opening at once when I switch back to development.

For `perform_deliveries` [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration) say:

> If this value is false, deliveries array will not be populated even if
>   delivery_method is :test.

I am also running sidekiq and redis, so I wasn't sure if I have to somehow set the environment on those.

Is there a way for me to completely prevent emails from being queued into the system in my testing envrionment?

Comment: Try to have different namespace for sidekiq. May be you are sharing dev namespace with test in redis. So when you run test you still push into queue for dev.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the sidekiq queue after you have run the server in the test environment. Or use other queue name in the test environment.

But the main thing is you should never run server in this mode.
For test you should use unit-tests or better [rspec](https://relishapp.com/rspec).

Comment: I don't see any reason not to run rails in test environment. Our end to end tests should be isolated from the dev environment.

Comment: test environment is setup to run tests. If you need additional environments for debugging, create a new environment.

Comment: I am using it to run tests. I can customize the test config file anyway I'd like.